# Flutter drawImage canvas keep giving error Object has been disposed

Tags: image, flutter, canvas

I have this pain function and in it I have this function to drawImage. Based on research I have run the following codes.

```
await rootBundle.load("assets/test1.png").then((bd) {
            Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
            ui.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then((codec) {
              codec.getNextFrame().then((frameInfo) {
                canvasWrapper.save();
                var bkImage = frameInfo.image;
                print("bkImage instantiated: $bkImage");
                canvasWrapper.save();
                canvasWrapper.drawImage(bkImage, Offset(x, y), new Paint());
                canvasWrapper.restore();
              });
            });
          });
```

I keep getting this error `Object has been disposed`. The issue it that when I run  `canvasWrapper.drawCircle(Offset(x + 5, y + 5), 8.0, paint1);` it runs perfectly? What could be the issue with drawImage?

Here is my testing of my full codes.

```
Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    

    final canvasWrapper = CanvasWrapper(canvas, size);
     _drawDetails(canvasWrapper)
}
Future<void> _drawDetails(CanvasWrapper canvasWrapper) async {

/*await rootBundle.load("assets/test1.png").then((bd) {
            Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
            ui.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then((codec) {
              codec.getNextFrame().then((frameInfo) {
                canvasWrapper.save();
                var bkImage = frameInfo.image;
                print("bkImage instantiated: $bkImage");
                canvasWrapper.save();
                canvasWrapper.drawImage(bkImage, Offset(x, y), new Paint());
                canvasWrapper.restore();
              });
            });

          });*/

          var paint1 = Paint()
            ..color = Color(0xff63aa65)
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;         

          double x = 10;
          double y= 20;
          
          canvasWrapper.drawCircle(Offset(x + 5, y + 5), 8.0, paint1);
          canvasWrapper.restore();

}
```

Comment: what is that `canvasWrapper`? how do you create it?

Comment: @pskink its just a class with canvas and size e.g. class CanvasWrapper {
  final Canvas canvas;
  final Size size;

  CanvasWrapper(
    this.canvas,
    this.size,
  );

Comment: are you creating the canvas by `Canvas(pictureRecorder)`?

Comment: @pskink nope I am not using pictureRecorder?

Comment: so where are you taking original `Canvas` from?

Comment: I am taking it via my paint function paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) also I define super.paint(canvas, size);

Comment: If you see I run this codes it works perfectly fine canvasWrapper.drawCircle(Offset(x + 5, y + 5), 8.0, paint1);?

Comment: ok, it seems you have a `CustomPainter`, right? if so, why dont you `drawImage` inside its `paint` method directly?

Comment: Yes I have customerpainter you are right. I have tried drawImage in the paint method same issue and error

Comment: post your complete code then

Comment: @pskink I have posted my full details codes above

Comment: @pskink so what is the trick it works meaning we have to get the image ready in the constructor. Actually I tried before this method only thing missing what this notifyListeners(); ? This did the trick ready. So how that helps actually ?

Comment: `notifyListeners` is used to "repaint" the `CustomPainter` - see the logs - `paint` method is called twice

Comment: So meaning it will do the loading of the images and prepare it then notifyListeners is some kind like telling it ready with the images is ?

Comment: yes, this is how it works

Comment: great I will test with more samples now